# Удаление данных больше определенного значения и группировка по неделям

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xcM2KNkLQ5P9dd8INU6OuOKfvY1gKeQp

Удалить количество оборот больше 7 и сгруппировать по неделям.

Реализовано:

```
article_read = pd.read_csv(
    '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Light/7/5579.csv', 
    delimiter=','
)
article_read2 = article_read.copy()
article_read3 =article_read2[lambda x: x['КоличествоОборот'] < 7]
article_read3.plot()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
article_read3['СуммаОборот'] = article_read3['СуммаОборот'].astype(float)
article_read3['КоличествоОборот'] = article_read3['КоличествоОборот'].astype(float)
article_read3 = article_read3.set_index(['Период'])
article_read3.resample('W', on='КоличествоОборот').sum().reset_index()
Ошибка "None of ['Период'] are in the columns"
```

После удаления выбросов [lambda x: x['КоличествоОборот'] < 7] надо, чтобы было по неделям и 'СуммаОборот', и 'КоличествоОборот'.

```
res = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Период", freq="W-MON"))["СуммаОборот"].sum()
res2 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Период", freq="W-MON"))["КоличествоОборот"].sum()


df4 = pd.DataFrame(res)
 df4_ = pd.DataFrame(res2)
merged_inner = pd.merge(left=df4, right=df4_, left_on='Период', right_on='Период')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
In [25]: df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\download\5579.csv", decimal=",", parse_dates=["Период"])

In [26]: df.dtypes
Out[26]:
Период              datetime64[ns]
КоличествоОборот             int64
СуммаОборот                float64
dtype: object

In [27]: df
Out[27]:
        Период  КоличествоОборот  СуммаОборот
0   2016-08-17                 3       134.22
1   2016-08-18                 1        44.20
2   2016-08-20                 4       131.60
3   2016-08-22                 1        45.50
4   2016-08-23                 2        88.40
..         ...               ...          ...
753 2019-11-15                 1        45.50
754 2019-11-17                 1        44.20
755 2019-11-21                 3       136.50
756 2019-11-22                 1        45.50
757 2019-11-25                 1        45.50

[758 rows x 3 columns]
```

Решение:

```
In [28]: res = (df
                .groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Период", freq="W-MON"))
                [["СуммаОборот", "КоличествоОборот"]]
                .sum()
                .reset_index())
```

Результат:

```
In [29]: res
Out[29]:
        Период  СуммаОборот  КоличествоОборот
0   2016-01-11       222.90                 5
1   2016-01-18         0.00                 0
2   2016-01-25         0.00                 0
3   2016-02-01         0.00                 0
4   2016-02-08         0.00                 0
..         ...          ...               ...
201 2019-11-18        89.70                 2
202 2019-11-25       227.50                 5
203 2019-12-02       136.50                 3
204 2019-12-09       512.12                12
205 2019-12-16       133.90                 3

[206 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('5579.csv', dtype={'Период':'str', 'КоличествоОборот':'int', 'СуммаОброт':'str'}, parse_dates=['Период'])
df['СуммаОборот']=df['СуммаОборот'].str.replace(',','.').astype('float')
```

Исходные:

```
        Период  КоличествоОборот  СуммаОборот
0   2016-08-17                 3       134.22
1   2016-08-18                 1        44.20
2   2016-08-20                 4       131.60
3   2016-08-22                 1        45.50
4   2016-08-23                 2        88.40
..         ...               ...          ...
753 2019-11-15                 1        45.50
754 2019-11-17                 1        44.20
755 2019-11-21                 3       136.50
756 2019-11-22                 1        45.50
757 2019-11-25                 1        45.50
```

Группируем и аггрегируем:

```
res = df[df['КоличествоОборот']<7]
res.groupby(res['Период'].dt.week)['СуммаОборот','КоличествоОборот'].sum().reset_index()
```

Результат:

```
    Период  СуммаОборот КоличествоОборот
0   1   1393.00 32
1   2   633.52  14
2   3   1087.20 24
3   4   1368.30 32
4   5   1355.40 32
5   6   1267.02 29
6   7   997.30  22
7   8   952.30  22
...    ...    ...
44  45  1369.80 32
45  46  1076.30 24
46  47  670.90  15
47  48  965.10  23
48  49  1616.32 40
49  50  1212.72 28
50  51  1168.62 26
51  52  1105.10 26
```

Comment: КоличествоОборот тодже надо

Comment: обновил ответ. Считать файл лучше так, как посоветовал MaxU